# Transforming data for kmeans and PCA

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
search_term = ['computer','usb port', 'phone adaptor']
clicks = [3,2,1]
bounce = [0,0,2]
conversion = [4,1,0]
```

I want to feed it into a kmeans model however i am having trouble transforming the lists into a matrix format so that it can be ingested by kmeans. I also want to reduce the dimensions with PCA so it can be visualized in a 2d plot.

This is what my code looks like:

```
X = np.array(clicks, bounce, conversion)
y = np.array(search_terms)
num_clusters = 3

pca = PCA(n_components=2, whiten=True).fit(X)
X_pca = pca.transform(X)

km=KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++',n_init=10, verbose=1)
km.fit(X_pca)

print km.labels_[:10]
```

This is the error i got:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Also, once the clustering is done, i would hope to be able to see which search terms fall into which cluster so i'm not sure if setting y = np.array(search_terms) is correct?

Please advise.

Comment: Which specific line of your code raises this error?

Comment: this line `X_pca = pca.transform(X)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work. Let me know if this is not the case.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

search_terms = ['computer','usb port', 'phone adaptor']
clicks = [3,2,1]
bounce = [0,0,2]
conversion = [4,1,0]

X = np.array([clicks, bounce, conversion]).T
y = np.array(search_terms)

num_clusters = 3

X_pca = PCA(n_components=2, whiten=True).fit_transform(X)

km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++',n_init=10, verbose=1)
km.fit(X_pca)
```

Comment: @jxn `encoder.classes_` will gives you all the unique labels

Comment: @jxn the `encoder` here is actually not much useful, because we are doing an unsupervised clustering and does not requires any y-label input. You can simply ignore those two lines.

Comment: @jxn You can test whether the algo do the clustering correctly by comparing `y[:10]` and `km.predict(X_pca)[:10]`

Comment: `y[:10]` gave me a list of 10 different numbers (is this the index number of the data?) while `km.predict(X_pca)[:10]`  gave me ( i believe the cluster label number)?

Comment: @jxn Can you post these two results in your post? both should return an array with 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0 alike.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82021/discussion-between-jianxun-li-and-jxn).

Answer (score 0):

How come you don't hit this

```
>>> X=np.array(clicks,bounce,conversion)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted
```

error?

I assume you want your data items arranged per rows:

```
X=np.array([clicks,bounce,conversion]).transpose()
```

if you want them per column, remove the `.transpose()`.